# Multiple web service (using HTTP/HTTPS protocol) in single baremetal machine

Tags: https, web-hosting, web, nextcloud, gitea

I am a newbie for web and network stuff.

I want to hosting the following web services for my personal use:

- Gitea
- Nextcloud
- pypiserver (Private pypi server)
- Ktra (private rust registry server)

I only have one machine which only have single network interface (single IP address).

I wish it can allocate URL for each service like below:

- Gitea: (https://my-ip-addr/gitea/)
- Nextcloud: (https://my-ip-addr/nextcloud/)
- pypiserver: (https://my-ip-addr/pypi/  <- for web browser; https://my-ip-addr/pypi/simple/  <- for pip).
- Ktra: (https://my-ip-addr/ktra/api/v1/...)

Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Start by learning about these general concepts: [virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) & [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first, you need to install the web server on your baremetal machine like apache or NGINX. Secondly, you need to make setup for each domain on you provider DNS CONFIGURATION. Next, in config files in e.g. NGINX you set the public directory for each domain. This is not complicated for http protocol but for https it is not simple for newbie.